# Java convert method to lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

what this method should look like in lambda expression ?

```
public Book returnBook(int idBook){
   for (Book b : records){
        if(b.getIdBook() == idBook){
            return b;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The stream version would primarily be made of `filter` + `findFirst`

```
return records.stream()
              .filter(book -> book.getIdBook() == idBook)
              .findFirst()
              .orElse(null);
```

Comment: or `Optional<Book> returnBook(int idBook)` works nicely as well :)